# Need to get right javascript syntax with input parameters

Tags: javascript

I have js line like that `agent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/)`
I need to make match parameters dynamic

So i tried to go like that `agent.match('/(' + param + ')/')` but it is not working.
Whatever I put in `param` it is matching.

What I did wrong? And what `/` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are dynamically generate RegEx strings, its always better to use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor. `/` is actually to tell JavaScript that you are going to use a Regular Expression literal. But when you put that inside quotes, it becomes a part of the string.

The simplest way to do this is to put them in a list like this

```
var data = ["iphone", "ipod", "ipad"];
```

And join them with `|` like this

```
agent.match(new RegExp("(" + data.join("|") + ")"))
```

This works because,

```
data.join("|")
```

will produce

```
iphone|ipod|ipad
```

We can concatenate `(` and `)` with that string to dynamically generate the pattern you wanted.